# How to reduce the size of qcow2 file when taking Android emulator snapshots?

Tags: android, adb, android-virtual-device, qemu, snapshot

We are trying to automate the creation of snapshots for testing our application. We may create up to 10,000 snapshots. For the sake of testing, we created ~400 snapshots. We noticed that the `~/.android/avd/Test.avd/userdata-qemu.img.qcow2` file quickly bloated to 32 GB! From what I understand, this is the virtual disk where the files of the AVD are stored.

We tried to compress the qcow2 file using the following command:

```
qemu-img convert -O qcow2 userdata-qemu.img.qcow2 dup.qcow2
```

After renaming dup.qcow2 to userdata-qemu.img.qcow2, the snapshots fail to load.

Can someone please answer the following questions? It would be really helpful!

- Why is this file bloating?
- Is there a way to split this file into multiple parts such that we can pull only the necessary data when loading a snapshot?
- How to reduce the size of the qcow2 file?

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 2):

A snapshot has to include the entire contents of the guest RAM at the point of the snapshot, and that's usually going to be the biggest contributor to its size. The snapshots are stored into the qcow2 file, which is why it grows when you add a new snapshot. I'm not sure there's much you can do about it, beyond configuring the guest with as little RAM as you can get away with, only creating as many snapshots as you mean, and deleting them when you're done with them.

Comment: What about the ram.bin file in the snapshot directory? Isn't that where the content of the RAM is stored?

Comment: Also, any idea why `qemu-img convert` failed?

https://serverfault.com/questions/432119/is-there-any-way-to-shrink-qcow2-image-without-converting-it-raw

Comment: Dunno. My answer assumes that Google haven't changed the stock QEMU method of handling VM snapshots.